# No intellisense for .ts files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm running Visual Studio Code 1.17.2 on Arch Linux to get started on Node.js/Angular4. To avoid mess caused by loosely types, I want to use TypeScript on the NodeJS server, too. So my main file is called `server.ts`.

The problem: I don't get intellisense on external packages like express or socket.io. For example, when I type `require('express').` there is no list with suggestions for methods. This seems caused by the extension: After renaming `server.ts`to `server.js` it works fine (typings were already installed using npm).

As my file is TypeScript and no JavaScript, I would like to use the correct `.ts` extension instead of `.js`. But how can I make intellisense work based on `.ts` extension?

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio code include TypeScript language but does not include the TypeScript compiler, tsc. To use it in visual Studio Code, you will have to install it manually. One way to do this is by the following command :

```
npm install -g typescript
```

After added the tsc compiler, you should get the correct intellisense for Typescript in Visual studio code.
To go forward with the typescript in visual studio code i advice you to read the following link : 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

Comment: I've already installed the package, the `tsc` command is globally avaliable in my shell. Also the typings are installed, eg `npm install @typings/socket.io --save-dev` but I still don't get any intellisense after typing `require('socket.io').`